# Which driver for ATI Radeon 9600 All-In-Wonder

Tags: 12.04, ati, radeon

I'm very new to Ubuntu and Linux for that matter, and wondering if anyone there found proper drivers for ATI Radeon 9600 All-In-Wonder.

The system (Ubuntu 12.04) doesn't let me change screes resolution and it's not recognizing the card.

I found this [page](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware) that shows some info but I'm really confused where to start and if it's possible at all to make everything work.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: This is normally supported by `radeon`. Are you having these troubles while using that driver?

Comment: Yep.. Im still having problems.. Initially i could not change the screen resolution but figured out I could do it by changing Xsetup as explained [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution) , but now my screen still doesn't respond nicely.. Full screen video is choppy and scrolling browser pages down and up is not smooth (it doesnt refresh fast enough). Now I'm wondering if I should switch to proprietary ATI driver. Not sure tho if a tested one exists so if someone has it, any info it would be very helpful.. Thanks!